# Different behavior of the same app on the same devices

Tags: android

I'll try to be precise as much as possible.
I wrote an app, the full code itself doesn't matter

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if(hasFocus){
        globalWidth = mainLayout.getWidth();
        refillData();
    }
}
```

it works perfectly on my device (sgs2 DarkyROM hd2.1 android version 4.0.3 also checked it on systems based 2.3 version for sgs2), another sgs2 with PilotX2.1, also it works on ASUS Transformer (android v4.2.1) and many other devices with different screen sizes.
I must say that it has different look depending on what device it run (it builds the main layout dynamically so its really notable if app run correctly or not).

But on some devices it has strange behavior. For example on HTC (htc sense 2.1) running android version 2.3.5 its somehow at line getWidth() returns the half or the actual screen's width. Or sgs2 4.2.1 android version it also returns strange result.

I tried to look up in google and stack overflow to find out are there any specific system differences that should be considered that has such a big influence on app but nothing. I don't use any kind of particular hardware of a device that could be implemented differently by system's developer.

What's the problem that I didn't take in mind? Can be that different kernels make the "problematic" behavior for my app? I thought it could be different ROMs, but I checked at least 6-8 different ROMs and had no problem.

If anyone familiar with that subject or met something similar, I would glad even for a link to webpage. I really frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can correct your measures by using [View.makeMeasureSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#makeMeasureSpec%28int,%20int%29)

```
mainLayout.measure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

int height = mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
int width = mainLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: thnx, I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: This didn't work. it even made some strange behavior. Putting this code 'mainLayout.measure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));' gives very strange results.